# Errors in building pd-extended

Tags: alsa

I get errors, likely related to alsa, when building from source pure data extended
(the last version - ) on ODROID C2, running Ubuntu 16.04.

To build I simply followed the instructions listed on the puredata.info 
(cd pure-data/packages/linux_make and then make instal)

I think I to have all the dependencies correctly installed.

Here the last lines of the build output:

```
pd-s_audio_alsamm.o: In function `alsamm_stop':
```

/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:998: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_drop'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1012: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_drop'
pd-s_audio_alsamm.o: In function `alsamm_close_audio':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:395: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_close'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:407: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:390: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_unlink'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:395: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
pd-s_audio_alsamm.o: In function`alsamm_stop':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:998: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_drop'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1012: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_drop'
pd-s_audio_alsamm.o: In function `alsamm_send_dacs':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1111: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_avail_update'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1133: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_state'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1216: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_mmap_commit'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1245: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_avail_update'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1256: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_state'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1321: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_mmap_commit'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1128: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_avail_update'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1133: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_state'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1148: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_avail_update'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1272: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_avail_update'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1253: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_avail_update'
pd-s_audio_alsamm.o: In function `alsamm_showstat':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1359: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_status_sizeof'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1359: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_sizeof'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1360: undefined reference to`snd_pcm_status'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_audio_alsamm.c:1364: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_dump'
pd-s_midi_alsa.o: In function`sys_alsa_do_open_midi':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:69: undefined reference to `snd_seq_open'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:83: undefined reference to`snd_seq_create_simple_port'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:67: undefined reference to `snd_seq_open'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:94: undefined reference to`snd_seq_create_simple_port'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:71: undefined reference to `snd_seq_open'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:101: undefined reference to`snd_seq_client_info_malloc'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:102: undefined reference to `snd_seq_get_client_info'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:103: undefined reference to`snd_seq_client_info_set_name'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:104: undefined reference to `snd_seq_client_info_get_client'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:105: undefined reference to`snd_seq_set_client_info'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:106: undefined reference to `snd_seq_client_info_free'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:109: undefined reference to`snd_midi_event_new'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:137: undefined reference to `snd_seq_port_subscribe_sizeof'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:137: undefined reference to`snd_seq_port_subscribe_sizeof'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:139: undefined reference to `snd_seq_client_info_sizeof'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:139: undefined reference to`snd_seq_client_info_sizeof'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:140: undefined reference to `snd_seq_port_info_sizeof'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:140: undefined reference to`snd_seq_port_info_sizeof'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:141: undefined reference to `snd_seq_client_info_set_client'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:145: undefined reference to`snd_seq_client_info_get_client'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:142: undefined reference to `snd_seq_query_next_client'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:149: undefined reference to`snd_seq_port_info_set_client'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:150: undefined reference to `snd_seq_port_info_set_port'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:151: undefined reference to`snd_seq_query_next_port'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:154: undefined reference to `snd_seq_port_info_get_port'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:157: undefined reference to`snd_seq_port_subscribe_set_sender'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:158: undefined reference to `snd_seq_port_subscribe_set_dest'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:159: undefined reference to`snd_seq_subscribe_port'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:163: undefined reference to `snd_seq_port_subscribe_set_sender'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:164: undefined reference to`snd_seq_port_subscribe_set_dest'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:165: undefined reference to `snd_seq_subscribe_port'
pd-s_midi_alsa.o: In function`sys_alsa_putmidimess':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:224: undefined reference to `snd_seq_event_output_direct'
pd-s_midi_alsa.o: In function`sys_alsa_putmidibyte':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:242: undefined reference to `snd_seq_event_output_direct'
pd-s_midi_alsa.o: In function`sys_alsa_poll_midi':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:257: undefined reference to `snd_midi_event_init'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:260: undefined reference to`snd_seq_event_input_pending'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:265: undefined reference to `snd_midi_event_decode'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:262: undefined reference to`snd_seq_event_input'
pd-s_midi_alsa.o: In function `sys_alsa_close_midi':
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:278: undefined reference to`snd_seq_close'
/home/odroid/Desktop/pdextended_sources/pd-extended/pd/src/s_midi_alsa.c:281: undefined reference to `snd_midi_event_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [pd] Error 1
make[4]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]:  **[all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]:**  [all] Error 2
make[1]:  **[pd] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2

I there anyone who managed to install pd-extended on ODROID C2 and 
can suggest a way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that pd-extended is not supported anymore, it is recommended to install pd-vanilla instead and use Deken to install the externals